# Как преобразовать строку в список?

Tags: python

Есть динамическая строка.

```
russia:moscow,20:45,dog:cat
```

Хочу передавать эту строку в post-параметр. Как я понимаю строку надо преобразовать в список. С помощью `.split()` не получается

```
 r = requests.get(url, params={'russia': moscow, '20':45, 'dog':cat})
```

Comment: как конкретно вы пытаетесь преобразовать с помощью split? Приведите свой код

Comment: Хранить время как ключ "20" и значение 45 - так себе идея.

Answer (score 1):

если бы ваша строка была бы такой:

```
"russia":"moscow","20":45,"dog":"cat"
```

тогда бы вам подошла библиотека `json`:

```
import json

text = '"russia":"moscow","20":"45","dog":"cat"'

data = json.loads("{" + text + "}")

print(data)
```

Но если у вас конкретно строки такого вида как вы привели, то небольшими преобразованиями (дописыванием кавычек) вы сможете превратить их в строки нужного формата для `json.loads`

Comment: А если у меня уже есть параметры в requests? как можно добавить этот массив requests.get(url, params={'token': token}) как сюда добавить верхний dict?

Comment: @Radzhab, т.е. обратно внедрить в строку? тогда можно соединить 2 словаря и используя методы Json обратно свернуть в строку

Answer (score 0):

```
In [36]: s = "russia:moscow,20:45,dog:cat"

In [37]: dict([x.split(":") for x in s.split(",")])
Out[37]: {'russia': 'moscow', '20': '45', 'dog': 'cat'}
```

Comment: А если у меня уже есть параметры в requests? как можно добавить этот массив requests.get(url, params={'token': token}) как сюда добавить верхний dict?

Comment: `
params = {'token': token}
payload = код из ответа
params.update(payload)
`